# How to add a new SwiftUI Color

Tags: colors, swiftui

How can i add a SwiftUI Color? Normally on UIKit you can create your own Colors but in SwiftUI con Color struct it's not easy like UIColor, but it's not complicate.

```
extension UIColor {
    UIColor(red: 219/255, green: 175/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Answer (score 37):

You can create your own **SwiftUI** Color with Color extension in a new file.swift

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    public static var myCustomColor: Color { 
        return Color(UIColor(red: 219/255, green: 175/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1.0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Such approach will evaluate new color every call. Approach with 'static let' is better (thanks @lmasneri).

Comment: @PavelShorokhov It depends. If You want to keep in memory all the colors all the time then it's fine. Sometimes computed properties are preferred because it does not keep in memory fetched colors.

Answer (score 9):

[You can create a color set like this one (which is called "black")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCXlS.png)

And after in your code just create an extension of Color:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    static let customBlack = Color("black")
}
```

And when you will use this customBlack, if you turn you app in darkMode it will use the dark appearance that you have set in your colorset.

You can use it like this in your code:

```
Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
.foregroundColor(.customBlack)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add **New color set** file in Assets.xcassets and colors with name.

Code:
Color("ColorName")

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new SwiftUI color with an extension of `Color`.
The extension does not need to be in a new Swift file, but it keeps your code clean to collect all Color extensions in one file.

### Method 1: Use the RGB initializer:

*(this is what OP was asking)*

```
extension Color {
    public static let myNewSwiftUIColor = Color(red: 219.0 / 255.0, green: 175.0 / 255.0, blue: 15.0 / 255.0, opacity: 1)
}
```

- Parameter `opacity` replaces `alpha`
- No need to call `UIColor` initializer
- Use `let`, not `var`.

### Method 2: Use XCode Color Set:

*(others have answered, but incomplete or problematic)*

```
extension Color {
    public static let myNewSwiftUIColor = Color("myNewSwiftUIColor")
}
```

### Use new color in your code:

```
Text("Example")
.foregroundcolor(Color.myNewSwiftUIColor)
```

---

### Hint 1:

I had been wondering **how to choose a color** in a Color Set in Assets.
For those who didn't find this yet:

- In `Assets.xcassets`, click on the Plus icon to add a Color Set.
- Give it a name by double clicking newly created color set 'Color' in the asset list. This will be the name string you have to provide in `extension Color`. E.g. `myNewSwiftUIColor`
- Click on one of the white color pads (Any Appearance / Dark Appearance).
- Then in the right column of XCode, click on the gauge icon to show Attributes Inspector.
- Make your color choice from the well known picker GUI ;-)

Seems simple once you know it.

---

### Hint 2:

As with all definitions, you can give a **inline documentation** that will show up in many places in XCode, e.g. Quick Help.

```
/// Like Color.green with a tad more yellow
/// - Note: Customized from Color 'Spring' from palette 'Crayons'
public static let crayonOffSpring = Color("crayonOffSpring")    }
```

I have found this helpful especially with colors, as to remember what it's for or where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Color+Extension.swift` file and add RGB's of your colors.

```
import SwiftUI


extension Color {
    public static var brokenWhite: Color {
        return Color(red: 238.0 / 255.0, green: 238.0 / 255.0, blue: 238.0 / 255.0)
    }

    public static var darkGray: Color {
        return Color(red: 57.0 / 255.0, green: 62.0 / 255.0, blue: 70.0 / 255.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had problems with Xcode not finding files that have a "+" in their names? I am on Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a named color on assets and put it in my extension, this way I don't have any problem switching between light and dark mode

```
extension Color {
   public static var primary: Color {
       return Color("primary-color")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    
    init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, opacity: Double = 1) {
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double(red) / 255.0,
            green: Double(green) / 255.0,
            blue: Double(blue) / 255.0,
            opacity: opacity
        )
    }
    
    static var twitterBlue: Color {
        return .init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255)
    }
}
```